# User Managed Notebook Auto Shut Down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have been researching to find a suitable and scalable functionality accross multiple project to auto-shutdown user managed notebook in Vertex AI to reduce the idle costs. I saw that "official" solution for this feature is only available for managed notebooks(https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/shut-down). In past some concerns has been raised for the similar issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237305892) which was marked as won't fixed.

Does anyone have any recommendation to establish a auto-shutdown policy for vertexAI user managed notebooks, any suggestions or workarounds are highly appreciated.

I have seen there are some functionalities available to use python/shell script for brute forcing to shutdown VM but as I said my concern of using reliable solutions at production level

Answer (score 2):

The official answer is to use [Workbench Instances](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/notebook-solution). Workbench instances include [idle-shutdown functionality](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/instances/idle-shutdown). Workbench instances are now available in Public Preview.

In the past we had an [script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/tree/ec96ce8267511ea77ffa9f5c5fe1aa8601bf10e6/notebooks/tools/auto-shutdown) that used CPU utilization, but is not recommended anymore as now Idle Shutdown logic is tied to Notebook execution activity.

Comment: does "not recommended" mean that using CPU load to initiate an shutdown procedure (whether or not using the script to which you have linked) no longer works (at all) for User Managed Notebook instances, or does it mean that developers are just trying to steer people toward the "Workbench Instances" so they don't need to mess with shutdown logic? If idle shutdown logic was tied to notebook execution, presumably that would still alter the CPU load.

Comment: Notebook execution logic is tied to the concept of sessions and kernel activity. When you run cells, Jupyter provides an API that provides execution activity (number of active sessions, status, etc). The new idle shutdown logic uses this API to understand if there is a user running code. In the previous logic CPU was used, but some customers have agents, additional software or some execution may not generate additional activity that can trigger shutdown inadvertently.

Comment: Since also User managed notebooks are fully customizable another option is to implement logic using Jupyter kernels vs CPU approach

Comment: We wrote an idle shutdown script based on CPU load. Two problems emerged. One is that the idle load threshold depends on the size of the VM.  The other problem is that if you install a security agent that scans for vulnerabilities at a regular interval the CPU appears to be busy and never shuts down. The new approach is tied to Jupyter kernel activity to avoid this.  But Workbench Instances don't allow Jupyter extensions, or to install complex libs like GDAL, which is the reason we couldn't use managed notebooks.  Could you publish an idle shutdown solution for user managed notebooks?

Comment: @intotecho I will discuss this internally and get back to you.

Comment: Just spotted an `Enable Idle Shutdown` control on the console for Unmanaged Notebooks under the SOFTWARE AND SECURITY tab. I selected it with 10 mins, but it hasn't shut down my idle notebook yet. I couldn't find the gcloud (alpha) equivalent yet.

Comment: Yes, we ported it to UmN (User Managed Notebooks). Will take a look why it may not be working.

Comment: We are rolling back a change that status in Instance was wrong. Can you wait for noon PST and try again?

Comment: UmN now supports Idle Shutdown

Answer (score 1):

There is now a clickops button in the user managed notebook gui, under the notebook's "Software and Security" tab, "Enable Idle Shutdown".

From our investigation, all this does is add a key value pair in the notebook metadata, "**idle-timeout-seconds**" (with a value in seconds for the shutdown to occur).

Modifying the metadata via terraform or cli commands can set this value, and doing it this way activates the GUI button with the value provided, and idle shutdown functions correctly.

This isn't really any official documentation on this though, so theoretically things may change at some stage.